# Are there any mature P2P frameworks/libraries in C#?

Tags: c#, frameworks, p2p

I am looking for a reliable P2P framework or library, preferrably natively written in C#, but can also work with something C# can interface with.  Have you came across or have worked with a solid one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at this link:

[Brunet: a remarkably great P2P library](https://github.com/johnynek/brunet)

Brunet is a Free Software (GPL licensed) library for P2P networking written in C# and developed using Mono, but it also runs on Microsoft’s .Net platform.

Comment: Good call Leniel!  Thanks.  I am concerned about the GPL though, since it means I cannot build anything commercial using it.  But it's a good start for a simulator.

Comment: Looks like this was changed to an MIT license and is now available at https://github.com/ptony82/brunet

Comment: Not sure someone else can re-license code like that? The (possibly) original GitHub library is still GPL

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked into the [Peer-to-Peer capabilities in the Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx) (WCF)?

Comment: Yes @casperOne thank you - the reason I am asking is because WCF is missing key issues, although it would definitely be a framework.  I was looking for a framework that would take into consideration overlays and routing mechanisms as well, and WCF seems to leave them for the "next levels".

Comment: @Etamar L.: You should point out in the question where WCF is deficient, so others can expand on those points if there is a solution.