# Notification system | library | framework for peer to peer app

Tags: c#, java, notifications, xmpp, websub

I'm about to code a pet project where part of the functionality relies in the notification from one machine to another.

The workflow is this:

1. Person A writes some content
2. Person A push a button or something saying: "I'm done"
3. Person B gets the update instantaneously

So, my first thought was, create a server and client and that's it! And that's what I'm about to do, but I thought there must be already a something for this.

I know about XMPP but I think it will be overkill ( I don't know actually ) 
I also heard about pubsubhubbub which looks exactly what I need, but I'm not sure since this is a peer to peer app.

I just need a simple way to let the other peer "Hey, I've finish here" ... that's it, a ping or something.

Is there some sort of peer to peer notification library|plugin|framework out here?

Comment: This question might appeal you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393660/are-there-any-mature-p2p-frameworks-libraries-in-c

Comment: Oh well, the answer is trivial and automatically gets converted to a comment :O Who knew :D

Comment: :-o Really? Wow.. :) I did upvote your comment anyway :P

Comment: PubSubHubbub is a protocol for communication between servers.  If you try to use it all the way to the clients you'll enter NAT hell.

Answer (score 1):

PubSubHubbub is particularly suited for communication between heterogenous entities (different companies, different web apps... etc), but it should also work for what you're trying to build.

XMPP would also work pretty well for that use case, but I guess it depends on the medium you want to use as well. If it's a web application, then, XMPP can be quite complex to deal with (thru BOSH or over websockets).

If it's a simple web app that you want to build, you should probably look at a solution that is javascript based.